# Copy least significant bits from an int to a long in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to copy the 8 least significant bits from an int to a given position in an unsigned long. My first approach was
`v1 = (v1 & ~0xf) | (v2 & 0xf);`
where `v1` is the `long` and `v2` the `int`. However, this would copy it at the very end and I am not sure how to modify it to be able to copy these 8 bits to any position in the `long`.

Comment: Read up about [bit shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work). Akari, you mention that you want to copy bits from one integer type to another, but then you say `v1` is a `float` instead. Which is it?

Comment: Do you know how to use [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) to move bits around? Also, I don't know what you're doing with that `float`, but I don't like it.

Comment: Can I still use shifting if I want to keep the rest of the bits intact in the long variable? And about float it was a type, I meant long

Comment: Just a note: 0xf corresponds to 4 bits, not 8.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the simple function you need:

```
#include <iostream>


void moveAByte( unsigned long int& destinationLong, const int& sourceInt,
                const std::size_t destByteOffset, const std::size_t sourceByteOffset )
{
    uint8_t* const firstByteAddressOfLong { reinterpret_cast<uint8_t* const>( &destinationLong ) };
    const uint8_t* const firstByteAddressOfInt { reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t* const>( &sourceInt ) };

    *( firstByteAddressOfLong + destByteOffset ) = *( firstByteAddressOfInt + sourceByteOffset );
}

int main( )
{
    unsigned long int v1 { 0x12'34'56'78 }; // a sample number
    int v2 { 0x19'ab'cd'ef }; // another sample number

    const std::size_t destByteOffset { 3 }; // Here choose between 0, 1, 2 ,3
    const std::size_t sourceByteOffset { 0 }; // the same here

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Before copying the byte " << sourceByteOffset << " of v2 to byte " << destByteOffset << " of v1" << "\n\n"
              << std::showbase << std::hex << "v1 address: " << &v1 << " --> " << "v1 value: " << v1 << '\n'
                                           << "v2 address: " << &v2 << " --> " << "v2 value: " << v2 << '\n';

    std::cout << std::dec << '\n' << "------------------------------------------------------" << "\n\n";

    moveAByte( v1, v2, destByteOffset, sourceByteOffset ); // source byte located in v2 is copied to destination byte located in v1

    std::cout << "After copying the byte " << sourceByteOffset << " of v2 to byte " << destByteOffset << " of v1" << "\n\n"
              << std::showbase << std::hex << "v1 address: " << &v1 << " --> " << "v1 value: " << v1 << '\n'
                                           << "v2 address: " << &v2 << " --> " << "v2 value: " << v2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Before copying the byte 0 of v2 to byte 3 of v1

v1 address: 0x8504fffc78 --> v1 value: 0x12345678
v2 address: 0x8504fffc7c --> v2 value: 0x19abcdef

------------------------------------------------------

After copying the byte 0 of v2 to byte 3 of v1

v1 address: 0x8504fffc78 --> v1 value: 0xef345678
v2 address: 0x8504fffc7c --> v2 value: 0x19abcdef
```

As can be seen, in this example, the least significant byte of `v2` which is **ef** is copied to the most significant byte of `v1` which was **12** but now it's **ef** too.

Using the function `moveAByte` you can easily copy any byte from `v1` to any position in `v2`.

**Note**: This code only works on ***little-endian*** machines and not on ***big-endian*** ones.

**Note**: On my platform (*Windows*), `long` is 4 bytes. On *macOS* and *Linux* it's 8 bytes. So don't forget to take this into account if you're on *macOS* or *Linux*.

Comment: This assumes *any position in the long* to be a *byte* position. The questions doesn't not specify that, nor *bit* position.

Answer (score -1):

Let's create a bitmask so that we can extract 8 least significant bits. If we calculate then we get 255 as our bit mask(11111111).
Then, suppose you want to place those 8bits in the third place, so we can use (<<) operator for shifting to our desired position.

long ans=(long)((var&bitmask)<<pos);

Answer (score -1):

Bit shifting is what you need, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work).
Basically, `0x1 << 2` add two zeros at the right of the number, so it becomes `0x100` or 4. Instead, `0x101 >> 2` remove the 2 least significant bytes, so it becomes `0x1`.

To get the 8 least significant bytes of an int you can bitwise-and with 255 (0xFF) then shift them to the left as much as you want and finally bitwise-or with the long number:

```
int v1 = 0xABAB;
unsigned long v2 = 0;
v2 = v2 | ((v1 & 255) << 5); // change 5 to the number you want
```